# Is there a way to identify only the new names in a data set appearing on a specfic date on GOOGLE SHEETS?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 columns on a google sheet that keeps updating with new data everyday:

1. Date
2. Usernames

What i want to arrive at?
I want date wise new usernames that were not present on the previous date on a new sheet.

Example:

- I have list of 10 names on 1st sep 2022
- Another 15 names were added on 2nd sep 2022 to the same list
- Out of the 15 names on 2nd sep 2022, 10 were present on 1st sep 2022
- I want the names of these 5 new users on a new sheet against the same date i.e.2nd sep 2022

I have also attached a sample excel sheet for reference. Looking forward to it.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sojDAHKIrTSNskqLCRbLTXFXXaiRQlhLHbWo_XCITnc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `E2` cell use- (See your sheet harun24hr).

```
=FILTER(C3:C,B3:B<=E2)
```

For `F2` cell use-

```
=FILTER(FILTER(C3:C,B3:B<=F2),INDEX(COUNTIFS(FILTER(C3:C,B3:B<=E2),FILTER(C3:C,B3:B<=F2)))=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(Data!B3:C, "select C,count(C) where C is not null group by C pivot B")
```

Comment: I think this will give only count but OP wants list of new names.

Answer (score 0):

In sheet *Terio*

***E2***

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(B3:B))
```

***E3***

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER($C$3:$C,$B$3:$B=E$2,NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH($C$3:$C,D3:D,0)))))
```

drag to right.

To exclude all previous users before a date in row 2 use this

***E3***

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2="","", FILTER($C$3:$C,$B$3:$B=E$2,NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH($C$3:$C,FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,$D3:D),"")),0))))))
```

another way

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2="","", FILTER($C$3:$C,$B$3:$B=E$2,NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH($C$3:$C,FILTER(FLATTEN($D3:D),FLATTEN($D3:D)<>""),0))))))
```

Bye